# Jupyter notebok kernel keeps dying while terminal logs "Could not open static file"

Tags: scikit-learn, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, python-3.7

Jupyter notebook takes ~5 seconds to import pandas and kernel is dying every time it's running a `get_dummies` or a `train_test_split` on a small dataset.

The issue appeared after I made a copy of a notebook and started working out of the copy, forcing the notebook to *Trust* the kernel. I've since reinstalled conda and OS, restarted computer, cleared cache and tried every other little hack discussed on developer forums.

This is what the terminal error logs look like:

```
[E 18:15:37.956 NotebookApp] Could not open static file ''

[W 18:15:38.024 NotebookApp] 404 GET /static/components/react/react-dom.production.min.js (::1) 17.00ms referer=http://localhost:8888/tree?token=6b3d
```

This is the jupyter packages I have:

```
jupyter --version
jupyter core     : 4.5.0
jupyter-notebook : 6.0.0
qtconsole        : 4.5.1
ipython          : 7.6.1
ipykernel        : 5.1.1
jupyter client   : 5.3.1
jupyter lab      : 1.0.2
nbconvert        : 5.5.0
ipywidgets       : 7.5.0
nbformat         : 4.4.0
traitlets        : 4.3.2
```

Comment: The linked comment in the thread "add missing react-dom js to package data #4772" https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/pull/4772#issuecomment-515794823 worked for me to get rid of the 404 error

Comment: @UweMayer Thanks for bringing up the github link. The workaround fixes the issue on my MBP + Mojave.

Comment: @UweMayer Thank you, this got rid of the errors in terminal. Kernel still gets stuck sometimes but it might be unrelated.

Answer (score 0):

You have reinstalled conda but you haven't updated your jupyter. Try using following command:

```
conda update jupyter
```

I also faced similar issue and after updating using above command my notebook was back to normal.

Comment: Thank you. Running conda update jupyter returned "All requested packages already installed." and checking with jupyter --version returned all the same versions as in the original question.